# QML Loader: set "source:" property once and only once

Tags: binding, qml, qt5, loader

Good morning, all,

I must maintain an existing QML application (which I cannot rewrite completely) and we need to delay the loading of most pages, so the startup of the application will be faster.

i.e.: I need to load a page, once and only once, at some point and I need to keep it loaded afterward (I've more than enough RAM for that).

So, I thought I could write something like this:

```
Loader {
    id: _userInfoLoader;
    source: (status != Loader.NULL || Global.currMenuId == MenuIds.SETTINGS) ? "pages/PageUserInfo.qml" : "" ;
    }
```

This code is intended to load the page "User Information" when the page "Settings" is opened (i.e. when the model's variable Global.currMenuId == SETTINGS)

(nb: the page "User Information" is a sub page of the page "Settings", so it's enough to load it when it's "parent page" is displayed).

Once this page "User Information" is loaded, its status will no longer be Null, it will be "Ready", "Loading" or "Error" and so the "source:" property should never change again once it is set.

Doing so, I get the dreaded error :

```
QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "source"
```

Do you know how to fix that? Thanks in advance for your thoughts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the the cycle is  `Global.currMenuId == MenuIds.SETTINGS` is true -> `source` is set -> `status` is updated-> `source` is set again -> `status` is updated again -> `source` is  set again ....

If you want it to do it once and only once, you could use `Connections` and procedural code:

```
Loader {
    id: _userInfoLoader;
    Connections {
        target: Global
        onCurrMenuIdChange: {
            if (!_userInfoLoader.source && Global.currMenuId == MenuIds.SETTINGS) {
              _userInfoLoader.source = "pages/PageUserInfo.qml";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked while keeping the QML source simple enough. I'm adopting your solution.